# Unset key page up and page down in emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, elisp

I can unset key left up right down use the function below.

```
(global-unset-key [left])
(global-unset-key [up])
(global-unset-key [right])
(global-unset-key [down])
```

But why i can't unset page up and page down using global-unset-key? The code below does not work.

```
(global-unset-key [pgup])
(global-unset-key [pgdn])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look for it with `C-h k *key-you-want-to-look*`.

```
;;; from *help* buffer, after C-h k pagedown
;; <next> runs the command scroll-up, which is an interactive built-in
;; function in `C source code'.

;;; from *help* buffer, after C-h k pageup
;; <prior> runs the command scroll-down, which is an interactive built-in
;; function in `C source code'.


(define-key (current-global-map) (kbd "<next>") nil) ; use whatever
(global-unset-key (kbd "<prior>"))                   ; you like
```